# page goes blank after partial refresh - xpages

Tags: file, file-upload, xpages

I'm getting a wired behavior while uploading file.
I then, in another part of the page activate partial refresh (not related to the upload file section at all). the hole page turn blank.
i found out that it is happening only id a data source is bind to the page.

here is a sample of html:

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Supplier"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:fileUpload id="fileAtt" immediate="false" required="true">
    </xp:fileUpload>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField1" immediate="true">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"></xp:text>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The File Upload control needs to be bound to a field on the datasource. Otherwise, you're asking the end user to upload an attachment without specifying where to store it, which is not an expected development approach.